# Is there a way to trigger GitHub Actions workflow on adding a certain file

Tags: github, action

I am able to trigger GitHub action when a certain file with name "file_name" changes (add/delete/modify) using this:

```
on:
  push:
    paths:
      - *file_name
```

Is there a way to trigger only when adding such file, and take no action when it is delete or modified?